# Unable to increase the width of amfunnel chart in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, amcharts, shinydashboard

I am trying to build a small dashboard application where I need to plot a funnel plot using amfunnel of ramcharts. Please see the below code and screenshot.

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
  fluidRow(
    box(
      title = "Box title", width = 6, status = "primary",
      amChartsOutput(outputId = "amfunnel",width = "100%")
    ),
    box(
      status = "warning", width = 4,
      "Box content"
    ),
    box(
      status = "warning", width = 2, 
      "Box Content"
    )

  )
)  
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$amfunnel <-  renderAmCharts({
    amFunnel(data = data_funnel, inverse = FALSE, label_side = "left")
  })
```

[Output dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIJta.jpg)

I want the funnel to fill the container/box. I tried increasing the box width but this is overlaying/restricting the other boxes in the page. How to increase the width of the funnel so that it fills the entire box.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are looking for. Should the top part of the chart (the blue part) have the same width as the box it is embedded in?

Comment: yes it is having the same width as the box. What I am looking for is to change the dimensions or resize the plot created by amfunnel.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer If you see the funnel plot is coming very narrow and lots of white space around the funnel plot in the box. So I want to increase the width / widen the funnel plot so that the plot will look nice and fills the entire box

Comment: Using the margins parameter does not work? `amFunnel(data = data_funnel, inverse = FALSE, margin_right = 0, margin_left = 190, label_side = 'left')`

Comment: Thanks @MartinSchmelzer It worked!!!! ... Thank you very much for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refering to the documentation of `amFunnel` you just have to use the margin parameters:

```
amFunnel(data = data_funnel, inverse = FALSE, margin_right = 0, label_side = 'left')
```

[image]